# "php artisan serve" forces HTTPS, where to disable locally?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am running Laravel 5.6 and when I run "php artisan serve" I am being redirected to http**S**://127.0.0.1:xxxx where xxxx rotates a bunch of port numbers.

Also, I am getting this error message in the console: "127.0.0.1:63227 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)" ands as you can see it has a seemingly random port number.

Needless to say I cannot run locally. I would like to know what is causing this so at least I may be able to disable it locally. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

`[Tue May 25 16:00:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:63230 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Tue May 25 16:00:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:63230 Closing
[Tue May 25 16:00:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:63231 Accepted
[Tue May 25 16:00:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:63232 Accepted
[Tue May 25 16:00:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:63231 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Tue May 25 16:00:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:63231 Closing
[Tue May 25 16:00:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:63232 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)`

There is NOTHING in the log.

Comment: Are you sure, you are not redirecting the user to the https version using .htaccess or any view?

Comment: Something on localhost probably served an HSTS strict header once in the past, so now your browser will refuse to talk to the host over anything but HTTPS. Try blowing your browser cache away _completely_, and then restart your browser, and even then it's a tossup.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method, that it was not already enforced using `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https')`.

If that is so, you can enable/disable it for certain environments.

```php
if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The port numbers in your log are the client port, you are not being "redirected" to it. When you run `php artisan serve` it tells you what port number is being used by the server:

```
$ ./artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Note the "http" in the URL. If you try to access this page with HTTPS, you will indeed see errors like this in the log:

```
[Tue May 25 15:16:22 2021] 127.0.0.1:64768 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Tue May 25 15:16:22 2021] 127.0.0.1:64768 Closing
```

The likely problem, if you aren't actually typing the URL incorrectly, is that your web browser is forcing HTTPS. Could be due to a browser extension or possibly HSTS from a previous server you had running.